# Differential equation: mixed boundary condition, how to solve numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, numerical-optimization

I have a differential equation (dot means derivative w.r.t time)
$$(\dot x, \dot y) = f(x,y)$$
and I am given the initial condition for $x$, but a final condition for $y$:
$$x(0),\qquad y(1)=g(x(1))$$ 
The second simply means that the final value of $y$ depends on the final value of $x$ with no known initial value.

Since I do not have an initial condition for $y$, my very crude attempt to solve it numerically is to pick a random $y(0)$, evolve the system in time, and compare the final value of $y$, $y(1)$, with the value it should have:

$$ I(y(0)) = \vert y(1)-g(x(1)) \vert ^2 $$

So when $y(1)=g(x(1))$ I will fulfill my condition. $I$ would be a non-negative "cost" associated with each initial condition. I applied a **gradient descent** numerically but this is quite unstable, meaning it doesn't converge. I also applied black-box optimizers based on Newton's method (the Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno algorithm) but it very rarely converges.

**Are there any other algorithms for solving mixed boundary conditions of this type?**

I'm also open to "rules of thumb" which, while not justified mathematically, can make solving optimization problems easier.

Context: I am trying to solve an optimal control problem. I apply Pontryagin's theorem and I get the mixed boundary conditions. $x$ and $y$ are actually vectors of dimension 4, but the above example captures the difficulty well enough in 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using optimisation, you can just solve a nonlinear equation. For each $\alpha$, evolve $x_{\alpha},y_{\alpha}$ by solving the corresponding differential equation (with initial condition $y(0)=\alpha$), and define $F(\alpha) = y_{\alpha}(1) - g(x_{\alpha}(1))$. Now you "just" need to solve $F(\alpha)=0$. I believe you can find inspiration in the "shooting method".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have no much better choice than trial & error, but this can be recast as a standard equation resolution problem: the unknown is $y(0)$ and the target function is $y(1)-g(x(1))$, where $x(1)$ and $y(1)$ are obtained by numerical integration, starting from $x(0),y(0)$.

You can use a derivative-free method, such as the secant.